# Where is the UML Diagram option in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, uml

I am trying to generate a diagram from IntelliJ 14. It is told in [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-diagram.html) to install the UML Support plugin. I do not find a such plugin on my computer:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is: don't use the community edition. It is limited in respect to diagram options.

Answer (score 1):

As I also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088011/how-to-setup-uml-diagramming-tool-powered-by-yfiles-for-intellij-idea/33089003#33089003):

> The community edition only supports a limited number of plugins. The
>   class diagram plugin is only supported in the Ultimate edition if I
>   remember correctly.
>
> You can always try a 30-day free trial of IntelliJ Ultimate in order
>   to generate your class diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I recall reading that one has to pay for IntelliJ to get that functionality. It is not in the free version.

Comment: That's what he said in his "answer to self" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Code Iris](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324?pr=idea) and [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/). It is a very useful tools especially PlantUML. Other tools of this type in the IDEA are paid.
[image]
[image]

Below PlantUML.
[image]

I hope it will help you.