# How to setup UML diagramming tool (powered by yFiles) for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, tool-uml

There is a cool diagramming tool for IntelliJ IDEA powered by yFiles.
Check out this video: https://youtu.be/cTg_ocVFmcs?t=36

I wonder if I can get this thing to work on IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition). The problem is there is no such plugin available in the plugins repo. How to perform the setup?

[image: UML Diagram Dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The community edition only supports a limited number of plugins. The class diagram plugin is only supported in the Ultimate edition if I remember correctly.

You can always try a 30-day free trial of IntelliJ Ultimate (or RubyMine).